# How to extract COMPLAINT features from texts in order to classify complaints from non-complaints texts

Tags: python, nlp, classification, feature-extraction, sentiment-analysis

I have a corpus of around 6000 texts with comments from social network (FB, twitter), news content from general and regional news and magazines, etc. I have gone through first 300 of these texts and tag each of these 300 texts' content as either customer complaint or non-complaint.

Instead of naive way of bag of words, I am wondering how can I accurately extract the features of these complaints and non-complaints texts? My goal is to use SVM or other classification algorithm/ library such as Liblinear to most accurately classify the rest of these texts as either complaint or non-complaint with the current training set of 300 texts. Is this procedure similar to sentiment analysis? If not, where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that bag-of-words is not so naive. It's actually a perfectly valid way of representing your data to give it to an SVM. If that's not giving you enough accuracy you can always include bigrams, i.e. word pairs, in your feature vector instead of just unigrams.